# extracting info from array objects

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, mongodb, express

```
{
"success": true,
"users": [
    {
        "photo": {
            "id": "users/m1ul7palf4iqelyfhvyv",
            "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpbdw6lxh/image/upload/v1665251810/users/m1ul7palf4iqelyfhvyv.png"
        },
        "_id": "634158087709697bfc50480b",
        "name": "updatetest1",
        "email": "updatetest1@shoppers.com",
        "role": "user",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-08T10:59:20.933Z",
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "photo": {
            "id": "users/ic2bfhlhvenrr6koesyo",
            "secure_url": "https://res.cloudinary.com/dpbdw6lxh/image/upload/v1665301682/users/ic2bfhlhvenrr6koesyo.png"
        },
        "_id": "63427cb276374e72e4d13a8b",
        "name": "test1",
        "email": "testuser1@gmail.com",
        "role": "user",
        "createdAt": "2022-10-09T07:48:02.603Z",
        "__v": 0
    }
]}
```

how can I extract user.name and user.email form mongodb users? and send the resposne to res.json?? I am extracting the specific info from all the users stored in database.

Comment: What have you tried so far that you're struggling with? Please add a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

User is an array, just map it.

```js
    const response = data.users.map(user=>{
      return {
        name: user.name,
        email: user.email
      }
    });
res.json(response);
```